# is there any online documentation available to perform sql like,in,join in a simple model in magento?

Tags: magento

I had created a simple model and mapped this model to a custom table, i need to filter and fetch values from this table.

is there any online documentation available to perform sql like,in,join in a simple model in magento? If so please let me know..

Thank you very much..!

Comment: [This link](http://bit.ly/hhtaEG+) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) link.

In this link there are samples for using like,in,eq etc., along with simple model as like addFieldToFilter('sku',array('eq'=>'n2610')), the actual solution will be at near to bottom of the page.

Also the Alan Strom - Magento articles link by Oğuz ÇELİKDEMİR is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Check maestro of magento Alan Storm's website.

[Alan Storm - Magento Articles](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento)